# CollapsibleToolbar not showing completely wrong

Tags: android

I decided I wanted to add a collapsible toolbar to a part of my app today. I followed a guide (as I really knew nothing about collapsible toolbars) and it totally went south. Everything is showing incorrectly. Please excuse my lack of experience with these types of layouts. Thanks in advance you wonderful people of StackOverflow

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="12dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/list_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:onClick="addItem"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/list_main"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_sheet_share"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/share" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_sheet_copy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_content_copy"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/copy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_sheet_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mode_edit"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/edit_literal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_sheet_delete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/delete" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It is because I (stupidly) didn't have the appbar layout as the parent for the collapsing toolbar, instead it was itself. Correct layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.ListCollapseActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/list_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:onClick="addItem"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/list_main"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_sheet_share"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/share" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_sheet_copy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_content_copy"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/copy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_sheet_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mode_edit"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/edit_literal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_sheet_delete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/delete" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```